# Why is Perl's chomp not doing what I want it to do?

Tags: perl

I am receiving output from some process (shown in `@result_listosp` below). When I try to chomp output is weird. I desire the following output:

```
origin-server-pool-1    http_TestABC    https_TestABC
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @result_listosp = (  # From backticks
   "origin-server-pool-1\n",
   "http_TestABC   \n",
   "https_TestABC\n",
);
chomp @result_listosp;
```

Output:

```
origin-server-pool-1http_TestABC   https_TestABC
```

Comment: why it did not remove space after second element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) is supposed to do, but it's not to add spaces?!

And it does not remove trailing whitespace either. If you want to remove trailing whitespace (including newlines) use the following instead of `chomp(@result_listosp)`:

```
s/\s+\z// for @result_listosp;
```

As for adding a space between elements, you can use

```
print(join(' ', @result_listosp), "\n");
```

or even just

```
print("@result_listosp\n");
```

Comment: Why it did not remove space after second element?

Answer (score 4):

The function `chomp` only removes the newline (`\n` in this case) character at the end of a line.

If you want to *trim* (remove whitespaces from the ends), you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub trim_elements {
    for my $i (@_) {
        $i =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    }
}

my @result_listosp = (  # From backticks
   "origin-server-pool-1\n",
   "http_TestABC   \n",
   "https_TestABC\n",
);

trim_elements @result_listosp;

for my $i (@result_listosp) {
    print $i;
}
```

As you can see, I didn't use parenthesis. That works only because the sub is declared before the call. If you declare the sub after the code, you need to use parenthesis.

Francisco

Answer (score 1):

If you have newlines in each line and you want to remove them, use chomp. If you want to concatenate strings with a space in between then use join:

```
my @result_listosp = (  # From backticks
   "origin-server-pool-1\n",
   "http_TestABC   \n",
   "https_TestABC\n",
);
print join (" ", map { /^\s*(.*?)\s*$/ } @result_listosp), "\n";
```

**Output**

```
origin-server-pool-1 http_TestABC https_TestABC
```

Comment: so you are saying that map does not go well with `s///`? do I need an explicit for loop?

Comment: Does this changes the input array I think its not changing the input array

Comment: it does not, but you can assign it back to the original